# SSIS to handle SQL binary data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am strugling wiith handling a sql binary(8) data type.
No matter what I try to do with it inside the SSIS package, it always fails with an error of: "Invalid cast specification"

Let me describe what I am tying to do in details:

1. I have a single row that I am assigning to a variable in a SQL Task in the control flow.

   `select max(LastRowVersion as bigint) as MinRV from MyTable`

   LastRowVersion is of datatype binary(8).

2.Then I am assigning the result to variable -  User::MaxRowVersion

If I configure MaxRowVersion to be of String or Object data type, then this part works fine.

3.Next I am opening a data flow task with the following select statement:

`select fields
 from AnotherTable
 where LastRowVersion  > ?`

and assigning `User::MaxRowVersion` to the query. 
Again LastRowVersion is of datatype binary(8) in the table  - AnotherTable.
Here is where I am getting the error that I mentioned above.

I have tried various types of playing with the `DT_BYTES` cast type in the expression of the `User::MaxRowVersion` variable, but it is failing.
I have also read that there is a possibility to open a C# script task to handle it or that Dynamic SQL can help, but I would rather keep the solution as simple as possible with no scripting if possible.

Thanks for the help,

Dani

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

- Keep MaxRowVersion as a Sting data type
- Cast the variable reference in the SQL statement

Example:

```
"

SELECT my_field 
FROM my_table 
WHERE LastRowVersion > CAST('" + @[User::MaxRowVersion]  + "' as MyDataType);

"
```